# After show down in cash game player left with less than SB/BB allowed to continue in next hand?

Tags: rules, cash-game

In some situations after a player loses a show down he might be left with some cash that is less than SB or BB.

Now what is the generally accepted procedure for next hand?
Exclude this player if he has less than SB/BB? Let him play next hands like normal (unless he is automatically all in due to blinds and gets a side pot)? Or is this decision up to the organizer of the game?

Answer (score 2):

I have not encountered a situation where a player who still has chips is not allowed to play in a cash game. Say they are playing a $5/$10 game, if a player is left with $2 after losing a hand, they can still play the next hand and will be playing for a side pot. If that player happens to be in the blinds the next hand, they will be all in and playing for a side pot as well.

Answer (score 1):

It is not the rule everyplace I have played or dealt. But generally the rule has been the player needs a full big blind to be dealt in a cash game.